# How to read a remote Protobuf file using URL in ASP .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, github, grpc

We're about to create a centralized Protobuf file repository in GitHub in our team. All the services will read the proto file from the same place so we will have better consistency. What I don't really understand is how the particular dotnet project could read the proto so it always has the newest version while compiling. I've discovered there's something called

```
dotnet-grpc
```

containing

```
add-url
```

command. If I run that command new Protobuf entry is added to my .csproj file

```
<Protobuf Include="test.proto" GrpcServices="Client">
    <SourceUrl>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{company}/{repo}/{branch}/{protofile}?token={token}</SourceUrl>
</Protobuf>
```

That should work I think but the problem is the token in the query string - I think it would be some kind of security breach if I just pasted it in there. So either I could parametrize it using the MSBuild (but that complicates a lot of CI/CD and so on), or there's some other clever way how could I retrieve it.

Is my approach with dotnet-grpc add-url command correct or not? Is there any other approach to read those remote files, which I should use? Finally, if not, then what to do with the token I've mentioned? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Rather than connect to a http server it may be better to use a network drive that you do not need a connection.  A shared network drive uses windows credentials for connection and is secure just like a https connection.

Comment: I recommend that you consider generating the stubs probably in the same GitHub repo where you're maintaining the protos. When the protos change, trigger rebuilds of the stubs and, for .NET consider a private NuGet repository Then, your .NET services can reference appropriately-versioned NuGet packages.